# Why Use <T> in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Recently I came across the below code.

```
public interface IBlog<T>
{            
     void Add(T blog);
     IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
     T GetRecord(int id);
     void Delete(int id);          
}
```

What is `T` here? What is the purpose of using it?

Comment: read about `Generic`. Here: [Introduction to Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Generics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example, you can have a method

```
T GetDefault<T>()
{
    return default(T);
}
```

and call

```
int zero = GetDefault<int>();
```

`T` in the method will be the type of an `int`.

In `c#` you have `List<int>` or `List<string>`, for example, this was implemented [using generics, read more...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you are wondering about are [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Generics provide a nice dynamic way doing stuff. You may or may not be aware of this already, but [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) use generics.

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>(); //Means everything within that list will be of Foo type
List<Bar> bars= new List<Bar>(); //Again, means everything within that list will be of Bar type
```